# Mcrypt issues after installing dnsmasq - OS X Mavericks

Tags: php, macos, mcrypt, dnsmasq

I'm getting the "Mcrypt PHP extension required." error message with every Laravel projects as well as phpMyAdmin. Everything worked just fine until I installed dnsmasq yesterday.

I tried a bunch of stackoverflow answers but no luck so far...

I'm wondering if dnsmasq has anything to do with this? Anyone else had a similar issue?

Running OSX Maverick 10.9.1, native apache (no mamp here), PHP 5.4.17, latest mysql/phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with the following installer (only works for OSX 10.8 and 10.9):

http://topicdesk.com/downloads/mcrypt/mcrypt-download